# Bitrix24: как найти из кода и изменить карточку по ее id?

Tags: php, rest, битрикс24, crm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Bitrix24, в коде найти конкретную карточку (лид CRM) по ее id, чтобы автоматически что0то в ней изменить?

Заранее благодарен за любой совет и помощь....

Comment: Опишите конкретнее задачу. Что вы хотите изменить, в какой момент? Битрикс облачный или коробка?

Comment: @АлексейМельников из коробки, вроде разобрался. Для тех, у кого такой же вопрос возникнет прилагаю метод: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/leads/crm_lead_list.php. Это надо в запросе Rest API отправлять. А подскажите, если я получил информацию один раз по параметрам, как отправить следующий запрос на основе предыдущего, если там, в Bitrix24 RestAPI и никакого кода... Может, знаете7